# Proving linear independence of transformed vectors from the linear independence of initial vectors.

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

So, I'm attempting to write a proof for the following theorem:

Let $f:V \to W$ be an isomorphism. If $(v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_r)$ is an r-tuple of linearly independent vectors in $V$, then the $r$-tuple of vectors $(f(v_1),f(v_2),\ldots,f(v_r))$ in $W$ is also linearly independent.

---

Proof Attempt:

Let $I = \{1,2,\ldots,r\}$. Consider the following linear combination of vectors:

$\sum_{k = 0}^{r} \alpha_k f(v_k) = 0$

By the linearity of $f$, the following chain of implications hold:

$\sum_{k=0}^{r} \alpha_k f(v_k) = 0$

$\implies \sum_{k=0}^{r} f(\alpha_k v_k) = 0$

$\implies f[\sum_{k=0}^{r} \alpha_k v_k] = 0$

$\implies \sum_{k=0}^{r} \alpha_k v_k \in \ker(f)$

By a previously proved result, we know that since $f$ is bijective, $\ker(f) = \{0\}$. Hence:

$\sum_{k=0}^{r} \alpha_k v_k = 0$

$\implies \forall k \in I: \alpha_k = 0$

That proves that the initial list of vectors in $W$ is a linearly independent list.

Can someone check if my argument above is correct? It feels correct but I don't think I used the bijectivity of $f$. Like, I feel like there's a stronger statement that can be made, where f can be injective only and the above statement still holds. Also, I'd appreciate any criticism whatsoever on the way I've written my proof.

Comment: It is correct. Bijectivity is not needed; injectivity is enough.

Comment: From the wording of the theorem, it seems to say that under the assumption that $v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_r$ are linearly independent as a given, then the vectors in $W$ are also.  I don't think you need to actually prove $v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_r$ are linearly independent.  I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much @JoséCarlosSantos

Comment: @ad2004 Oh did i prove that $(v_1,v_2,...,v_r)$ are linearly independent? I thought I just used that in the last line of my proof?

Comment: No, you did not prove that (and you were not supposed to do that). You *assumed* that the set $\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$ is linearly independent and you *deduced* that then the set $\{f(v_1),\ldots,f(v_n)\}$ is linearly independent too.